# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'date': it is not exactly10characters long

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

in my code i have two entities BusDetails and User. The User and the BusDetails has many to many relationship. Whenever i try to book bus, the data is saved in the join table in database but i get this exception: 
**Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: it is not exactly10characters long]]**

User Table:

```
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int u_id;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be empty")
    private String name;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty(message = "Username cannot be empty")
    private String userName;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty(message = "please enter number")
    @Size(min = 10,max = 10, message = "10 digits required")
    private String number;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=8,message = "Minimum 8 characters required")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "u_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "r_id"))
    public Set<Role> roles;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_busdetails", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "u_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bus_Id"))
    public Set<BusDetails> bus = new HashSet<BusDetails>();


    //gettersAndSetters
```

BusDetails:

```
@Entity
@Component("BusDetails")
public class BusDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int bus_Id;


    @Column
    public String fromDestination;

    @Column
    public String toDestination;

    @Column
    @DateTimeFormat
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column
    private String travels;

    @Column
    private String bus_Type;

    @Column
    private String seats_Available;

    @Column
    public String fare;

    @Column
    private String departure;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "bus")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<User> user = new HashSet<User>();

    //gettersAndSetters
```

BookController:

```
@PostMapping("/bookbus")
    @ResponseBody
    public BusDetails bookBus(@ModelAttribute BusDetails bus) {



        System.out.println(bus.getDate());
        return busDetail.bookBus(bus);

    }
    @InitBinder     
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
         binder.registerCustomEditor(       Date.class,new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy- 
    MM-dd"), true, 10));   
    }
```

BookService:

```
public BusDetails bookBus(BusDetails bus) {


        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        String currentPrincipleName = authentication.getName();



        User user = userRepo.findByUserName(currentPrincipleName);


        user.getBus().add(bus);
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(bus);


        userRepo.save(user);



        return bus;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used @ModelAttribute in the controller means all parameters is pass in String format.

In your case is to format from `String` to `Date`.

```
@Entity
@Component("BusDetails")
public class BusDetails {

    //...

    @Column
    private Date date;

    //setter(can add or modify) should be custom like below :
    public void setDate(String date){
        try {
            this.date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // ...getter & setter
}
```

Comment: i dont know what change i made, before it was working without the above modification.thanks a lot.

Comment: @PariskritA.Moktan If you use `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute`, everything's okay.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Date Parameters at the Application Level**

```
@Configuration
class DateTimeConfig {
    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService conversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = 
          new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        registrar.setDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        registrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

        // other desired formatters

        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

First, we create DefaultFormattingConversionService with a false parameter, which means Spring will not register any formatters by default.

And then, we manually register new patterns for date and date-time formats in the DateTimeFormatterRegistrar object.